# jQuery Tabs possible without nav <ul>?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tabs

All of the jQuery Tab systems I've encountered use a `<ul>` with links, which is separate from the tab content div. Is there a way to code the following (I'm using pseudo code here)...

```
<div class="tab"><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab1">Content for Tab 1 here .......</div>
<div class="tab"><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab2">Content for Tab 2 here .......</div>
```

Layout would look like the following:

**[Tab1] [Tab2] [Tab3] [Tab4]**
[Tab contents is fixed here below tabs]

Answer (score 1):

No, the tab titles need to be grouped at the top. Some widgets, like accordion, let you specify the element type of the headers, but even then, the markup has to be a certain way. Do you have some limitation preventing you from doing what jQuery requires?

Comment: The issue is that I'm pulling info to generate the tabs from a Wordpress loop which means I'm having creating the tabs then to rewind the query to generate the tab contents. Is there a way of of absolutely positioning the tab contents div?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `ol` tags but I'm not to sure if that will help out at all. You could also try to create a table if you're making tabs.